# Считать бинарный файл

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь считать шестнадцетиричный файл но нечего не получается, делаю так

```
void Read() {

 FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\test.save", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

 int leng = (int)stream.Length;

 byte[] bufer = new byte[stream.Length];

  stream.Read(bufer, 0, leng);

  ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();

  string res = ascii.GetString(bufer, 0, leng);

  richTextBox1.AppendText(res);

  stream.Close();
 }
```

а так работает (кое-как), но файл считуется очень долго
     void Read() {

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\test.save", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

int leng = (int)stream.Length;

 byte[] bufer = new byte[stream.Length];

 stream.Read(bufer, 0, leng);

 ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();

 char[] chars = ascii.GetChars(bufer);

  foreach (char ch in chars) {

  string symb = ch.ToString();

  ichTextBox1.AppendText(symb);

   }

   stream.Close();
            }
```

Помогите пожалуйста.
П.с тега для форматирования C# кода не нашел=(

Comment: А что в вашем понимании "шестнадцатеричный файл"?

Comment: хотел написать бинарные , но чет отвлекся и написал не то)
Если нужно могу загрузить файл..

Comment: Ваш код должен делать то, что вам нужно. Что работает не так?

Comment: вот что я получаю в результате <quote>24</quote> и пару каракуль  с этого файла https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E8788102BA5E11A5!598&authkey=!ADWoQ59CqIgPIjQ.
Второй вариант работает как надо, но пока он считует файл можно пойти по спать))

Comment: Ожидаемый эффект от попытки чтения нетекстового файла как текстового. А что вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: А почему так сложно?

    byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

Ну или потоковая обработка с

    IEnumerable<string> content = File.ReadBytes(filename);

если файл очень большой.

Comment: Да, уточни вопрос. Что тебе нужно из этого файла получить и в каком виде сохранить?

Comment: И разумеется вы же не хотите выполнять медленные файловые операции в UI-потоке, правда?

Comment: я не надеюсь считать файл полностью, я хочу хотя бы так считать как считать как его открывает notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var buf = File.ReadAllText("filepath", Encoding.ASCII);
```

[Третья ссылка в выдаче гугла.](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%23+how+to+read+text+file+in+ascii+format&oq=c%23+how+to+read+text+file+in+ascii+format&gs_l=hp.3...2607.5303.1.5661.4.4.0.0.0.0.151.487.1j3.4.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.TA6Dbd8X3tw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=20760f6d07000947&bpcl=39314241&biw=1593&bih=957)

Вариант с заменой нулей на пробелы (чтобы нормально отображалось в RichTextBox):

```
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("12345.wotreplay", Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder((int)reader.BaseStream.Length + 1);
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var chr = (char)reader.Read();
                if (chr == 0)
                    chr = ' ';
                builder.Append(chr);
            }

            var result = builder.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Результат:
"24" и пару символов(которые не копируются).
я искал в гугле...

Comment: @cyber_ua: где такой результат? в переменной `buf`? что означает "не копируются"?

Comment: Значит кодировка не ASCII. Покажи свой файл.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E8788102BA5E11A5!598&authkey=!ADWoQ59CqIgPIjQ

Comment: Все там нормально читается. Именно этим кодом.

Comment: VladD, я не говорил что не копируется, я говорил что не правильно считывает файл, второй вариант(там где считывается по байтно) работает он больше минуты читает файл..

Comment: Вообще для нормального чтения таких файлов есть класс StreamReader. Тебе разбирать формат придется, если конечная цель не состоит в простом выводе содержимого на форму.

Comment: @Flammable, пробывал  StreamReader но таже фигня..
делал так
<code>
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\12345.wotreplay",Encoding.ASCII);

            richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();

            sr.Close();
</code>

Comment: @Flammable, и насчет нормально читается , вот если мне кто то не верит)
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-n9uFyyd9hwU/ULz-QbYIcoI/AAAAAAAAAI0/2gBBOv2k9qA/s1152/2.jpg
с права как должно, с лева как у меня (код под формой)

Comment: Твой второй вариант работает долго, потому что ты делаешь кучу ненужных преобразований.
Кривой результат из твоего первого комментария был получен потому, что в начале файла есть несколько нулей. Первый нулевой байт считается концом строки, поэтому RichTextBox не показывает все остальное.
Читай файл побайтно, используя StreamReader. Для формирования строки используй StringBuilder. Перед вызовом StringBuilder.Append() проверяй, является ли очередной символ нулевым. Если да - пиши вместо него пробел и читай дальше.
Вся эта тривиальщина хорошо описана на MSDN, стоит только поискать.

Comment: `"12345.wotreplay"` :)

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай [пример простой программы, реализующей запись и чтение бинарного файла](http://kojt.blog.ru/93507283.html)

Comment: да я уже вообщем разобрался, читало файл правильно, но просто выводило не правильно...

Comment: Классический пример С++ника, переехавшего на .NET: освобождение памяти, стековые буферы и прочее - в конкретном примере это выглядит просто смешно.

Comment: В .net всё делается гораздо проще:

    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("source");
    File.WriteAllBytes("destination", bytes);

Если файл _реально_ большой, больше, скажем, 10 Мб, делайте так, как вот тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030971/276994